# Bibliography is not plotting

Tags: biblatex

So I'm using a template I've found on latextemplates.com and I'm trying to print the bibliography but nothing seems to be working. Also no error warning appears, it just simply skips it.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\begin{document}
  some text bla bla bla
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

I've changed the `backend` to every one I've found online: `bibtex`, `biber` and `bibtex8`.

And it seems that every time I compile it creates a `*.bib` file automatically.

What can I do?

Comment: The `library.bib` file is created by *you* (maybe with the help of an external software program such as Zotero or jabRef). The job of `biblatex` (with assistance from either bibtex or biber) is to create a `.bbl` file (which contains the formatted bibliography), based on various pieces of information, such as which items in the bib file are being `\cite`d in the body of the document -- and hence which should show up in the formatted bbl file as well. Do you have any `\cite` instructions in the body of your document? Did you run `biber`? Please explain your workflow in more detail.

Comment: I'll try to clarify. So I have the 'library.bib' file because i created it using mendeley but when I compile my example.tex file it generates a example-blx.bib file everytime. I'm not sure what run 'biber' means. I just use TexMaker software and run 'Compile' everytime.

Comment: Are you getting a bbl file? Specifically, a file called `\jobname.bbl`, where `\jobname` is the name of your main tex file?

Comment: Yes I have a *.bbl file but it don't change in every compile run. I have my bibfile with the same name as the main tex file, is it important?

Comment: Well, is what shows up in the pdf file correct?

Comment: Use `backend=biber` (as you already do) and make sure you actually run Biber https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If `example-blx.bib` is generated in each run you are running Biber and not BibTeX. If you run Biber you should either get a properly typeset bibliography or you should find errors and warnings in the `.blg` file. In the latter case, please share the `.blg` with us. Remember to delete all temporary files first (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...), then do a full compilation run (pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX) and then check the output and log files.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked really well!

edit: thank you for the edits, I wasn't understanding how you guys did that haha

Comment: Good, I have voted to close your question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Hope you are OK with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used one of my reference file in the following code, and it compiles:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
some text bla bla bla

\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

The command  `\nocite{*}` is used to print the entire bibliography, then you need to run pdfLaTeX + BibTeX + pdfLaTeX + pdfLaTeX.

It should work fine.

A variant with the package biblatex is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\bibliography{library}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

some text bla bla bla

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Ps: i) The bibliography does not print if no command `\cite{.}` are found, hence the `\nocite{*}` instruction.

ii) If you do not have the bibliography style authoryear, bibTeX will complain and say "*couldn't open style file authoryear.bst* " and the bibliography won't show up...

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: Are you sure this answer works with the OP's `biblatex`-based workflow?

Comment: Actually as \moewe pointed out, I was compiling using `biblatex` instead of `biber`. As soon I compiled with `biber`, the bibliography was printed. But thank you very much for your reply, I could gather other info I didn't knew.